# Validation error message when activating a journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

Send Email: Apple Trade Confirmation - Update

> Email Activity: Apple Trade Confirmation - Update -- The email specified for the job did not pass validation. EmailID: 4492 There is an error in your email. Please contact your customer service representative. Error 1: Script SET Statement Invalid An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail. Script Expression: RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Quoted__c", "Quoted__c:Trade_Confirmation__c", "Quoted__c:Trade_Confirmation_URL__c", "Quoted__c:Channel__c", "Quoted__c:PreferredLanguage__c", "Quoted__c:Account_Name__c", "Id", "=", @id) MemberID: 10959867 JobID: 0 The function call includes an invalid number of repeating parameters. Repeating parameters must be included in full sets. Function Call: RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Quoted__c", "Quoted__c:Trade_Confirmation__c", "Quoted__c:Trade_Confirmation_URL__c", "Quoted__c:Channel__c", "Quoted__c:PreferredLanguage__c", "Quoted__c:Account_Name__c", "Id", "=", @id) Function Name: RetrieveSalesforceObjects Number of Parameters in Repeating Set: 3 Number of Repeating Parameters in Call: 7 Number of Invalid Repeating Parameters in Call: 1 Invalid Content: set @quotedRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Quoted__c", "Quoted__c:Trade_Confirmation__c", "Quoted__c:Trade_Confirmation_URL__c", "Quoted__c:Channel__c", "Quoted__c:PreferredLanguage__c", "Quoted__c:Account_Name__c", "Id", "=", @id) There is an error in your email. Please contact your customer service representative. Error 1: Script SET Statement Invalid An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail. Script Expression: RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Quoted__c", "Quoted__c:Trade_Confirmation__c", "Quoted__c:Trade_Confirmation_URL__c", "Quoted__c:Channel__c", "Quoted__c:PreferredLanguage__c", "Quoted__c:Account_Name__c", "Id", "=", @id) MemberID: 10959867 JobID: 0 The function call includes an invalid number of repeating parameters. Repeating parameters must be included in full sets. Function Call: RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Quoted__c", "Quoted__c:Trade_Confirmation__c", "Quoted__c:Trade_Confirmation_URL__c", "Quoted__c:Channel__c", "Quoted__c:PreferredLanguage__c", "Quoted__c:Account_Name__c", "Id", "=", @id) Function Name: RetrieveSalesforceObjects Number of Parameters in Repeating Set: 3 Number of Repeating Parameters in Call: 7 Number of Invalid Repeating Parameters in Call: 1 Invalid Content: set @quotedRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Quoted__c", "Quoted__c:Trade_Confirmation__c", "Quoted__c:Trade_Confirmation_URL__c", "Quoted__c:Channel__c", "Quoted__c:PreferredLanguage__c", "Quoted__c:Account_Name__c", "Id", "=", @id)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In RetrieveSalesforceObjects you need to prescribe a set of fields as one parameter.

```
RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Quoted_c', 'Field1,Field2,Field3', 'Id', '=', @id)
```

It also looks like you missed getting rows count before line #9.

```
SET @quotedRowCount = RowCount(@quotedRows)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not referencing the fields properly in the retrieve function.  I may have told you incorrectly in your other question.

Also, there's a difference between the SF object and the sync'd data extension fields. The function is retrieving the data directly from SF, while you're referencing fields as if they're in the sync'd DE.

Perhaps you can describe how you've configured your entry event.

```
%%[

var @id, @row, @quotedRowCount, @tradeConfirmationURL
set @id = AttributeValue("Quoted__c:Id")

set @quotedRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
                    "Quoted__c"
                    , "Id, Trade_Confirmation_URL__c"
                    , "Id", "=", @id)

set @quotedRowCount = rowcount(@quotedRows)

if @quotedRowCount > 0 then

   set @row = row(@quotedRows,1)
   set @tradeConfirmationURL = field(@row,"Trade_Confirmation_URL__c")

endif

]%%
<br>tradeConfirmationURL: %%=v(@tradeConfirmationURL)=%%
```