# Redirect to URL from Salesforce Lookup

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

This is my AMPscript code:

```
%%[

 /*Lookup Quoted__c Object*/
 Set @quoted__cRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Quoted__c", "Id,Trade_Confirmation_URL__c,Trade_Confirmation__c", "Id", "=", @Quoted__c:ID)
 set @Quoted__cRowsCount = rowcount(@Quoted__cRows)

 if @Quoted__cRowsCount > 0 then
   set @tradeConfirmationURL = field(row(@accountRows,1),"Trade_Confirmation_URL__c")
 endif

 if @Quoted__cRowsCount > 0 then
   set @tradeConfirmation = field(row(@accountRows,1),"Trade_Confirmation__c")
 endif


]%%
```

I have a button that redirects to `Trade_Confirmation_URL__c`.  Here is that code:

```
<table width="200" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">
    <tr>
       <td style="color: #000001; text-align: center; font-size:12px; font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;" valign="top" align="left">
            <a href="%%=RedirectTo(Quoted__c:Trade_Confirmation_URL__c)=%%" alias="Apple Trade Confirmation Link" target="_blank">
            <img alt="Complete Trade" src="http://image.contact.phobio.com/lib/fe5215707c610d757313/m/1/3afb3e1e-d1dc-480b-a185-4f06cf345dba.png?b=1519762800000" style="display: block;" width="200" height="40" border="0"></a>
         </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

I got this error message from Salesforce

> -- Error:- ExactTarget.OMM.InvalidFunctionException: The specified
>   attribute or custom object field name was not found for this client. 
>   Function Call: RedirectTo(Quoted:Trade_Confirmation_URL__c)  Attribute
>   or Field Name: Quoted:Trade_Confirmation_URL__c  Error Code:
>   OMM_FUNC_SYNTAX_ERR 
>   - from OMMCommon

Comment: please refrain from asking for help in your posts, especially in the title. it will not help draw more attention nor does it make it more relevant. And so your posts are easier to read, make sure you format them properly =) thanks

Comment: sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference the variable in your redirect -- the one you set in the first part:

```
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(@Trade_Confirmation_URL__c)=%%" >
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/40">
</a>
```

Are you sure the first part works?  Your lookup variable doesn't seem correct.  Shouldn't it be just `@ID`?

```
%%[

var @id, @row, @quotedRowCount, @tradeConfirmationURL
set @id = AttributeValue("Quoted__c:Id")

set @quotedRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
                    "Quoted__c"
                    , "Id, Trade_Confirmation_URL__c"
                    , "Id", "=", @id)

set @quotedRowCount = rowcount(@quotedRows)

if @quotedRowCount > 0 then

   set @row = row(@quotedRows,1)
   set @tradeConfirmationURL = field(@row,"Trade_Confirmation_URL__c")

endif

]%%
```

Comment: I wonder why I am getting a Bad Request - Invalid URL
HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.

Comment: so should I remove the "=" and "ID" and just leave the @ID?

Comment: No, you need that.  My point is that I don't think this reference is correct: `@Quoted__c:ID` .  Maybe I'm wrong.  You're not showing your entire script, so it's hard to tell.

Comment: That is the whole script.

Comment: So what about [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/220085/5202) then?  Did you implement what I described?   If so then all you should need for your link is `%%=RedirectTo(@Trade_Confirmation_URL__c)=%%`

Comment: Also @AndreGreen you need to mark your answers as resolved when they solve your issue. This is not just to provide well deserved points to the user, but it also makes it easier for others to find the correct solution when searching our community.

Comment: @Gortonington how do you mark the correct solution? New to this sorry.

Comment: There should be a greyed out checkmark next to each answer to your question. You just click that and it will mark it as the correct answer